# Joining 3 tables - MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

Subjects:

```
ID_subject    Subject_name
```

Questions:

```
ID_question   Question   ID_subject
```

Answers

```
ID_answer     Answer     ID_question
```

Is it possible to make a selection where the result will be all the answers from 3rd subject? I tried to make a double JOIN but that did not work, it returned me all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT a.ID_answer, a.Answer FROM Answers a 
JOIN Questions q ON q.ID_question = a.ID_question
JOIN Subjects s ON s.ID_subject = q.ID_subject
WHERE s.ID_subject = ID_of_third_subject
```